# Sonos to Slack - how to show the songs we play in a Slack channel

Tags: slack, sonos

I work on a distributed team and I want my remote colleagues to know what we're playing in the office. We use Sonos. We bump beats everyday. How can I automatically send played tracks into Slack so remote my remote colleagues can feel involved?

I've glanced at a few solutions that are suggested at [this post in the Sonos Community](https://en.community.sonos.com/controllers-software-228995/slack-integration-6548363).

- [Zenmusic](https://github.com/htilly/zenmusic)
- [Jukebot](https://github.com/estiens/jukebot)
- [sonoslack](https://github.com/ewiner/sonoslack)

The first 2 give me a lot more than I need (I don't need write access from Slack to Sonos). The third gives me exactly what I need, but all of these solutions require that I run code on a server somewhere (I think). This sounds more complicated than it's worth.

Is there a simpler way of sending tracks from Sonos to Slack?

Answer (score 1):

Because Sonos runs on your local network, you need a service that can connect to both it and to Slack running on the internet. This means any solution will need to run locally rather than just online.

This doesn't necessarily mean a server, you could run the service on a PC on the same network as Sonos or something like a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi).

Answer (score 0):

**Office DJ** has been working somewhat well to send songs played in Spotify to Slack:

https://officedj.co/

[image: Office DJ]

I know I originally required connecting Sonos to Slack, but with our team now being FULLY distributed, Spotify is a bit more democratic.

Still feel like I haven't found the perfect product here.